# how to connect nodejs code with custom cms

Tags: node.js, express, content-management-system, backend

i want to make Content Management System that can run on **nodejs** code.help me out in this project .I know that cms  is written in php but i want to add the functionalities with the help of nodejs or expressjs.help me in connecting the cms application with nodejs .

Answer (score 0):

CMS is a type of application, and is not uniquely written in PHP. Developing the entire content management system is a large project with many moving parts. To get a sense for how involving it is, you can take a look at [this example project](https://itnext.io/building-a-node-cms-with-keystonejs-mongo-db-react-and-redux-part-i-ae5958496df2) where somebody walks you through one particular way of implementing a content management system in NodeJS. However, your implementation will vary depending on your goals of the CMS you are looking to develop.